# subscribe point clouds to octomap

Tags: ros, octomap, octomap-mapping, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a node which listen to topic 'rgbdslam/batch_clouds' from 'rgbdslam' package and edit it to publish the required points clouds as topic 'new_batch_clouds'. Now, I need to use 'octomap' to save both point clouds as map. And both has common 'tf' from package 'rgbdslam'.

I tried to make the node 'octomap_server' to subscribe the topic 'new_batch_clouds'. From seeing the codes, I think a topic named 'cloud_in' is subscribed for point clouds. In normal procedure, I don't understand how 'rgbdslam/batch_clouds' would be subscribed by 'octomap_server'

So, now I need two maps. One from the topic 'rgbdslam/batch_clouds', that is done usually. Then, I need another map using 'new_batch_clouds' from the new node and 'tf' from rgbdslam package'. How to make it?

Thanks in advance, for the suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45637/subscribe-point-clouds-to-octomap/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use topic remapping (check out [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/9248/how-do-you-remap-a-topic/) question).

For instance, you can use the following launch file to let the octomap server subscribe to your new_batch_clouds topic:

```
<launch>
  <node name="octomap" pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node">
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="new_batch_clouds" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-10-11**:
oh! i forgot about the basic feature... thank you lorenz...